# Why post_save signal is not working here?

Tags: python, django, signals

I created a signal that creates profile when a user is created. Previously, the same code was working fine in other projects. Here, I don't know what I am doing wrong that it doesn't work and doesn't create profile for created users. This is the signal.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print(instance)
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

All the imports are done properly, and here I imported that in my app:

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

In case if you want to look at profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} Profile".format(self.user.username)
```

Since I created a signal, for all new created users it should add that `default.jpg` as default profile picture.

But if I create a new user, login then go to profile page it shows something like this:

[image]

and if I go to admin and add this profile picture manually it works fine. One final thing I added the following settings in `urls.py` as well:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Please help me fix it, it has been 3 hours I tried all possible ways but couldn't make it work. Thank you for your help.

edit: 
`template`

```
<div class="media">
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit-2: `default.jpg` is added here!
[image]

Comment: Does `Profile` is created for each new `User` (i.e. signals are loaded)? Can you share piece of template that renders `src` attribute?

Comment: Is your default.jpg is actually in the correct path? Just check your image url and image path in your project. I doubt it is different, that's why you are getting no src.

Comment: @Gasanov I just updated the question added template therein

Comment: @BidhanMajhi, yes, question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src(unknown)` happens if you have no `profile` attached to your user. This most likely means that your signals are not triggered, which is because they were not loaded, which is because your `UsersConfig` app was not loaded in first place.

There are 2 ways of loading app. [Proper one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-users) will be:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# ...
'yourapp.apps.UsersConfig'
]
```

Another way is to set `default_app_config = 'yourapp.apps.UsersConfig'` in `yourapp/__init__.py`. Note that it is [not recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) anymore for new apps.

After that you will probably want to modify `signals.py` as well - if you try to save `Users` that doesn't have `Profile` attached, that will trigger exception.

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, 'profile'):
        instance.profile.save()
    else:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Thank you bro, you saved me. I added app in installed apps as 'users', it is weird it didn't run but the way you said, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add save method inside `Profile` Model:

First import Image from PIL

```
from PIL import Image
```

Then your Profile Model be like :

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

       def __str__(self):
         return "{} Profile".format(self.user.username)

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().save()

           img = Image.open(self.image.path)

           if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
               output_size = (300, 300)
               img.thumbnail(output_size)
               img.save(self.image.path)
```

Here image size is decreased. If you need you can use otherwise you can directly save the image without decreasing the size.

Comment: yes, we are overwriting it to decrease the size of image. I did even that and didn't work. still getting `src(unknown)` for image

Comment: Have you added  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') and
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' in settings.py file

Comment: Yes, I did. here:

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: yes, please see the updated question. I added where is default.jpg